# Why am I getting a response not ready error

Tags: python

I have written this basic script to GET site data from our Mist wireless system. I am getting an error on the conn.getresponse() line.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "I:\Python Stuff\My Scripts\Mist_Device_Details_JSON.py", line 13, in <module>
    res = conn.getresponse()
  File "C:\Users\W792114\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 1311, in getresponse
    raise ResponseNotReady(self.__state)
http.client.ResponseNotReady: Idle
```

Here is the script. What I have found while searching is that it's not liking the reuse of the conn variable. One of my peers is able to run it with no problem though???

```
import http.client
import json

conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("api.mist.com")

payload = ''
headers = {
  'Authorization': '#################'
}

conn.request = ("GET", "/api/v1/sites/", payload, headers)

res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()

jsonOutput=json.loads(data)
```

Comment: I think it's `conn.request("GET", ...)`, i.e. a method call, not `conn.request = ("GET" ...)`.

Comment: That was it. Thank you very much